# When a duplicate video is uploaded no status is returned

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

### Checking a status on a duplicate video ID does not return.

When I upload a duplicate video, I can see that the message shows that there is a duplicate in my YouTube Studio as expected:

> Processing abandoned
>
> File is a duplicate of a video you have already uploaded

Then I go to the API to grab the status of the video by using the ID.

The problem is that no results come back, here is the result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/erMOlj0RdIpN5zRhRnmUipx6Crw\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": []
}
```

*This was working for me, and suddenly without changing anything, it's not working anymore.*

I can get the status on all over videos that are not duplicates.

I am looking for a status of "rejected" and a reason to be "duplicate"

Comment: What's the URL request you're using?, have you checked whether there are errors?

Comment: Hi @MauricioAriasOlave - Using the API Tester tool at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list and the result with no error is what I posted in my OP.